# sending cookies with BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am doing a login to a server (different IIS then the one which the client is), the response of this login is a cookie

> Set-Cookie:session-token=7ed240cd-fd41-464c-9ccd-d43097ef4d7c; domain=x.x.x.x; path=/

the login is done via JQuery POST, the server is ODATA server - I am initilizing breeze with

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({
        modelLibrary: "backingStore",
        dataService: "OData"
    });

    var breezeDataServiceSettings = {
        serviceName: serverUrl + 'odata',
        hasServerMetadata: true
    };



    var dataService = new breeze.DataService(breezeDataServiceSettings);
    manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService });

    manager.metadataStore.fetchMetadata(dataService).then(succeded, failed);
```

so far all is ok, however when I am sending requst to get entity (also fetch metadata) the cookie isnt being sent, i have tried to send request with JQuery and the cookie is sent
also I have tried to add headers to the ajax breeze adapter (add the cookie) but it is being ignored.

How can it be solved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting AJAX headers in Breeze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616445/setting-ajax-headers-in-breeze)

Comment: dont think so, as I am using ODATA and accorind to the code it isnt using the regular ajax adapter

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution -
in datajs-1.1.1 under

```
request: function (request, success, error)
```

when creating the createXmlHttpRequest object I added

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```